# React js I have to click two times on search button to get result from api and my UI get changed

Tags: reactjs

When I click on the search button I send a POST request and get data from the server.
The thing is the first time it returns an empty array based on my console log report, but when I click on the button for the second time it has the values from the server and my UI changes. Why does this happen? is it because async-await process? what should I do to solve this problem?

```
export default function Home() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const obj = { searchTerm };
  const [receivedData, setReceivedData] = useState([]);
  const [episList, setEpisList] = useState([]);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true);
  const [currentUrlIndex, setCurrentUrlIndex] = useState(0);

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(obj),
  };

  const submitSearch = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/', options);
    const data = await response.json();

    //COMMENT--- Manipulating and using the result I get from server
    setReceivedData(data.body.result);

    const epName = receivedData.map((x) => {
      return x.name;
    });

    setEpisList(epName);
    console.log(epName);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <main>
           <div>
                <ReactPlayer
                  controls={true}
                  url={`videos/${episList[currentUrlIndex]}.mkv`}
                />
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <SearchBox
            value={searchTerm}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <SearchButton onClick={submitSearch} />
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you delete and repost this question? Edit: Huh... Okay are you using multiple accounts? Or is this a homework question? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70155782/api-first-time-after-refresh-returns-empty-then-is-not-empty-every-time-after) seems like the exact question you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies in the following code:

> ```
> //COMMENT--- Manipulating and using the result I get from server
> setReceivedData(data.body.result);
>
> const epName = receivedData.map((x) => {
>   return x.name;
> });
> ```

`setReceivedData(data.body.result)` will update `receivedData` **on the next render**. The current execution context still uses the old (stale) value. Meaning that `epName` will lack behind, because it is based on the old `receivedData`.

So how do you solve this? Quite simple, store the new value in a variable.

```
// create a shadow variable that holds the new value
const receivedData = data.body.result;
setReceivedData(receivedData);

const epName = receivedData.map((x) => {
  return x.name;
});
```

The above creates a new variable `receivedData` and assigns it the new value. This does not update the state, so we still need to call `setReceivedData(receivedData)` which update the component state. After that we use this variable instead of the state.

---

If you don't quite understand shadow variables, imagine the above code like this:

```
// create a variable that holds the new value
const newReceivedData = data.body.result;
setReceivedData(newReceivedData);

const epName = newReceivedData.map((x) => {
  return x.name;
});
```

A shadow variable does the exact same, but uses a name that is already defined in an outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

So, when you set a react state, you schedule a rerender. When that happens, the body of your function(-al component) is going to run again, recreating all variables, including `submitSearch` where you store your function.

`submitSearch` closes over several references to variables who's "content" changes every time that function is redefined (every render), and makes several calls to set state. I think stuff like this is best avoided, since it can be a little bit annoying to debug.

Consider letting `submitSearch` have a single responsibility: to retrieve backend data to a state.

```
const submitSearch = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/', options);
    const data = await response.json();
    setReceivedData(data.body.result);
}
```

Then you can generate side effects on that state

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setEpisList(receivedData?.map((x) => x.name)
},[receivedData, setEpisList])
```

But, episList is really just a nice-to-have subset of receivedData, you could redefine it per render, without having a state for it.

```
const episList = receivedData?.map((x) => x.name)
```

If you want to take it a step further, consider relocating things out of the component, and consider errors

```
const myLocalhostApi = {
    get: (options) => fetch('http://localhost:3001/', options).then(r => r.json()
}

const MyComponent() {
    const [receivedData, setReceivedData] = React.useState([])

    const options = // options

    const handleSubmit = myLocalhostApi.get(options)
        .then(setReceivedData)
        .catch(myErrorHandler)
    
    const episList = receivedData.map((x) => x.name)

...
```

Comment: Sorry but didnt work, could you please provide me an example in jsfiddle or something? I really appreciate your help

Comment: sure: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-wind-3r5mh?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are trying to update in synchronous time a variable with asynchronous data. To solve you problem you have to use `then` after the `fetch` statement.
You have to rewrite your `submitSearch` function like that:

```
const submitSearch = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
            setReceivedData(result);
            const epName = receivedData.map((x) => {
               return x.name;
            });

            setEpisList(epName);
            console.log(epName);
         })    
};
```

In this way after the `fetch`, if everything is ok, you enter in the `then` and there you update your state.

Comment: Thank you I tried it but nothing changed, just like when I'm using async await.